# Python enum with custom class with mandatory keyword arguments

Tags: python, enums

I am trying to create an enum with custom class which has mandatory positional arguments.

```
class Coord:
  def __init__(self, *, x, y):
    self._x = x
    self._y = y
```

I would like to make several enums with this class.
Somthing like:

```
class IntCoord(Coord, Enum):
  ONE_ONE = Coord(x=1, y=1)

class FloatCoord(Coord, Enum):
  ONE_ONE = Coord(x=0.1, y=0.1)
```

So that I can use them in other class like:

```
class System(Generic[T]):
  @classmethod
  def get_one_one(cls) -> T:
    return NotImplemented

class IntSystem(System[IntCoord]):
  @classmethod
  def get_one_one(cls) -> IntCoord:
    return IntCoord.ONE_ONE

class FloatSystem(System[FloatCoord]):
  @classmethod
  def get_one_one(cls) -> FloatCoord:
    return FloatCoord.ONE_ONE
```

After that, I want to compare the enums:

```
IntCoord(x=1, y=1) is IntSystem.get_one_one()
```

I am having a hard time defining the `Coord` class.
It seems it is not possible to instantiate `Coord` enum class by `Coord(x=1, y=1)`

Is there a good way to achieve this with enum?
Or better reasonable implementation?

Full script is as follows:

```
from enum import Enum
from typing import Generic, TypeVar


class Coord:
    def __init__(self, *, x, y):
        self._x = x
        self._y = y


class IntCoord(Coord, Enum):
    ONE_ONE = Coord(x=1, y=1)


class FloatCoord(Coord, Enum):
    ONE_ONE = Coord(x=0.1, y=0.1)


T = TypeVar('T', bound=Coord)


class System(Generic[T]):
    @classmethod
    def get_one_one(cls) -> T:
        return NotImplemented


class IntSystem(System[IntCoord]):
    @classmethod
    def get_one_one(cls) -> IntCoord:
        return IntCoord.ONE_ONE


class FloatSystem(System[FloatCoord]):
    @classmethod
    def get_one_one(cls) -> FloatCoord:
        return FloatCoord.ONE_ONE


if __name__ == '__main__':
    int_one_one = IntSystem.get_one_one()
    float_one_one = FloatSystem.get_one_one()

    print(IntCoord(x=1, y=1) is int_one_one)
    print(FloatCoord(x=0.1, y=0.1) is float_one_one)
```

Errors are:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 11, in <module>
    class IntCoord(Coord, Enum):
  File ".pyenv/versions/3.9.0/lib/python3.9/enum.py", line 228, in __new__
    enum_member.__init__(*args)
TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Comment: please edit the code in your question to be a [mre] of your best attempt and show the _full_ error message.

Comment: @barny updated the question with reproducible example!

Comment: Feels like an x,y problem: ignoring your current attempt, what are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to make a type for each `system` and use it as input param for other functions in the `system`. If `system` has `draw_point` method, then I want them to get `IntCoord` as input, so that I can call `int_system.draw_point(IntCoord(x=1, y=1))`, which is for more specific typing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you are having with `Coord` and `Enum` is that you have said your enum is also a `Coord`, and a `Coord` takes two arguments -- but you are only giving your enum member `ONE_ONE` a single argument... a `Coord`.

There are two ways around this problem:

- don't use a `Coord` in your enum member (and lose your keyword (not positional) arguments):

```
    class Coord:
        def __init__(self, x, y):
            self._x = x
            self._y = y

    class IntCoord(Coord, Enum):

        ONE_ONE = 1, 1
```

- don't use `Coord` in your enum header (and keep your keyword arguments, but add `property`s so that `blah._x` and `blah._y` still work]:

```
    class Coord:
        def __init__(self, *, x, y):
            self._x = x
            self._y = y

    class IntCoord(Enum):
        #
        ONE_ONE = Coord(x=1, y=1)
        #
        @property
        def _x(self):
            return self.value._x
        #
        @property
        def _y(self):
            return self.value._y
```

---

It does get easier if you use the `aenum`<sup>1</sup> library instead:

```
from aenum import Enum, enum

class Coord:
    def __init__(self, *, x, y):
        self._x = x
        self._y = y

class IntCoord(Coord, Enum):
    #
    ONE_ONE = enum(x=1, y=1)
```

and in use:

```
>>> IntCoord.ONE_ONE
<IntCoord.ONE_ONE: enum(x=1, y=1)>

>>> IntCoord.ONE_ONE._y
1
```

Note that in all the above cases, retrieving `IntCoord.ONE_ONE` by value is a little trickier than usual:

1. `IntCoord((1, 1))`
2. `IntCoord(Coord(x=1, y=1))`
3. `IntCoord(enum(x=1, y=1))`

--

<sup>1</sup> Disclosure:  I am the author of the [Python stdlib `Enum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html), the [`enum34` backport](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/enum34), and the [Advanced Enumeration (`aenum`)](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/aenum)  library.